# Does $[L:L\cap \mathbb{R}]\leq 2$ hold for any number field $L$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

As the title says, I am wondering if $[L:L\cap \mathbb{R}]\leq 2$ holds for any number field $L$.
(A number field is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}.$)

If $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, then we know that the fixed field of $\{1, \text{conj}\}$ in $L$ is exactly $L\cap \mathbb{R}$, and therefore by Galois theory,
$$[L:L\cap \mathbb{R}] = \#\{1, \text{conj}\} \leq 2.$$
(When $L\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, this number is $1$; otherwise, it is $2$.)

So what if $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is *non-Galois*? Does the statement remain true or is there any counterexample? Thank you for any help.

Comment: What about $L = \Bbb Q(e^{\frac{2i\pi}3}\sqrt[3]2)$?

Comment: @WhatsUp Yeah you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N/\Bbb Q$ be the normal closure of $L/\Bbb Q$, with $G = \operatorname{Gal}(N/\Bbb Q)$.

Assume $N$ is imaginary (otherwise $L \subset \Bbb R$), so there is a $\sigma \in G$ that is induced by complex conjugation.

Then $L = N^H$, and $N \cap \Bbb R = N^{\langle\sigma\rangle}$, so $L \cap \Bbb R = N^{\langle H, \sigma \rangle}$, and $[L : L \cap \Bbb R] = [\langle H, \sigma \rangle : H]$.

If $H$ is normal, then $\langle H, \sigma \rangle$ is just $\langle\sigma \rangle H$ = $H \cup \sigma H$, so the index is $2$.

But if $H$ is not normal then $\langle H, \sigma \rangle$ can be pretty much anything, even $G$.

For example, it is well-known that if $f$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $p$ prime with exactly $p-2$ real roots, then the splitting field of $f$ has Galois group $S_p$. Then $\sigma$ acts like the permutation $(12)$, which together with $(12\cdots p)$ generates the group, so take $H = \langle(12\cdots p)\rangle$, then $[L : L \cap \Bbb R] = p!/p = (p-1)!$.